# How to access function in the same typescript file from another export function in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular13

I am trying to access a function from another export function in the same ts file. But not working. So, How to do it?

app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'bus-poc';
  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  addingNumber(total:any){ 
   console.log(total);
  }
}

export function sum(a: number, b: number) {
  const num = a + b;
  this.addingNumber(num);
}
```

hello.component.ts:

```
import { sum } from './another-file';

sum(50, 10);
```

Demo : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vewk4c?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: The setup like this doesn’t seem to make much sense. Reusable functions are fine as externals that can be imported, but here the function you want to reuse is actually the one inside the component? This can work though if you make addingNumber static. Then you can use it as AppComponent.addingNumber().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your hello component, you need to make that call within a function:

```js
import { sum } from './app.component';

@Component({...})
export class HelloComponent {
   ngOnInit(): void {
     sum(1, 2);
   }
}
```

And then, in your `app` component, you cannot use the `addingNumber` function from outside, unless you instantiate the class `AppComponent`.

```js
@Component({...})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'bus-poc';
  ngOnInit(): void {}

  addingNumber(total:any){ 
   console.log(total);
  }
}

export function sum(a: number, b: number) {
  const num = a + b;
  const appComponent = new AppComponent();
  
  appComponent.addingNumber(num);
}
```

If your `AppComponent` class has some dependencies injected, you will need to provide them. Not sure what logic you're trying to achieve but this is how you would do it.